# Regex to split PascalCase string into separate words

Tags: regex

Previously to split a PascalCase string into separate words I used the regular expression below:

```
(.)([A-Z]|\d+)
```

This will work for inputs such as `Photo100`, `PhotoMax`, `PhotoMaxOrig`. But when faced with a string like `Photo100Orig` my regular expression above doesn't split that string into three parts.

How can I more elegantly modify my regular expression to support strings like `Photo100Orig`?

Comment: Try `(.)([A-Z]|\d*(?=\d))`

Comment: If your string contains only ascii letters and digits, you can use `\B([A-Z]|\d+)` with ` $1` as replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming C# as your language,

```
var pattern = @"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z]|(?<!\d)\d)";
```

can be used in

```
var words = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

to get an array of the word components.